# HTML: center span in div but expanding to fill all the available space in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please, look at this short HTML snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="pt-5 position-relative text-light bg-dark">
  <span class="ms-4 position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle">▲</span>
  <span class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle h5" style="text-align:center;">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </span>
  <span class="me-3 position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle">▲</span>
</div>
```

As you can see, the text area does not use all the available space:

[image]

I tried to add `width:90%;` but it loses the horizontal positioning.
What class should I change to have the text centered (no matter if it needs one or two lines) but filling all the available space until the ▲ symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all your elements are absolutely positioned (which is not a great idea btw) you can make the element take all the area using `end-0 start-0` and text-align will do the job

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="pt-5 position-relative text-light bg-dark">
  <span class="ms-4 position-absolute top-50 start-0 translate-middle">▲</span>
  <span class="position-absolute top-50 translate-middle-y end-0 start-0 h5 text-center">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
        </span>
  <span class="me-3 position-absolute top-50 end-0 translate-middle">▲</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Feel free to propose a better approach to achieve the same result if the absolute positioning is not a great idea!